# Overbraces hovering too far above matrix for some reason?

Tags: matrices, arrays, brackets, braces

I have a matrix with two overbraces above it but they are not directly above it, there is a fair amount of space between the braces and the matrix and I can't see why it is happening.

```
documentclass[a4paper,12pt,times,numbered,print,index]{article}   
\RequirePackage[left=37mm,right=30mm,top=35mm,bottom=30mm]{geometry}
\RequirePackage{libertine} 
\RequirePackage[small,bf,labelsep=space,
    tableposition=top]{caption} 
\usepackage{multirow}  
\usepackage{subfig,amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb,braket}
\usepackage{algorithm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms
\usepackage{algpseudocode}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash$}p{#1}<{$}}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\[
  \begin{array}{@{}r@{}}
    \overbrace{\begin{array}{@{}*{5}{C{1.5em}}@{}}
      &&&&&&
    \end{array}}^{\text{$m$ terms}}
    \overbrace{\begin{array}{@{}*{5}{C{1.5em}}@{}}
      &&&&&&
    \end{array}}^{\text{$m$ terms}} \hspace*{10pt}\\[-.5\normalbaselineskip]
  \Rightarrow: 
  \hspace*{-\nulldelimiterspace}
    \left[\begin{array}{@{}*{10}{C{1.5em}}@{}}
        1  & 1  & 0 & \cdots   & \cdots    & 0  & 0  & 0          & \cdots  & 0     \\
        0  & 0  & 0 & \cdots   & \cdots    & 1    & -1 & 0          & \cdots  & 0 \\
        0  & 0        & \cdots     & \cdots   & \cdots    & \cdots           & \cdots      & \cdots        & \cdots  & 0 \\
        0  & 0 & \cdots & \cdots         & \cdots    & \cdots          & \cdots              & \cdots        & \cdots  & 0 \\
    \end{array}\right]
  \end{array}
\]

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

How can I get these braces directly over the matrix as is usually the case?

Comment: sonicboom once again your examples don't compile. It seems you are just changing the class to `article` and pasting here. You need `\newcolumntype{C}...` etc. stuff here too

Comment: @percusse I did that because that is the alteration someone else made to my code when they answered my questions yesterday and I presumed that made it good to compile. I have edited in the \newcolumntype, I will be more careful in future.

Comment: It still has multiple errors: ! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.

! Too many }'s.

! LaTeX Error: \begin{document} ended by \end{figure}.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I will be alot more careful in future.

Comment: Don't presume, *check* that it compiles. The `array` package is missing, and there are still errors. Same for your other question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please test the code before posting, your code had multiple errors

```
! LaTeX Error: Illegal character in array arg.

! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.

! Too many }'s.

! LaTeX Error: \begin{document} ended by \end{figure}.
```

So I had to guess fixes for those to guess the problem that you were actually facing which is that you had put the brace over a "white" array but even though the cells are empty such an array takes up one full line.

I think you want something more like this

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,times,numbered,print,index]{article}   
\RequirePackage[left=37mm,right=30mm,top=35mm,bottom=30mm]{geometry}
\RequirePackage{libertine} 
\RequirePackage[small,bf,labelsep=space,
    tableposition=top]{caption} 
\usepackage{multirow}  
\usepackage{subfig,amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb,braket}
\usepackage{algorithm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms
\usepackage{algpseudocode}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx

\begin{document}

\[
  \Rightarrow: 
  \hspace*{-\nulldelimiterspace}
    \left[\begin{array}{@{}*{10}{c}@{}}
\noalign{\vspace{-20pt}}
\multicolumn{5}{c}{}&
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\text{\scriptsize$m$-terms}}&
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\text{\scriptsize$n$-terms}}\\[-7pt]
\multicolumn{5}{c}{}&
\multicolumn{2}{c}{$\downbracefill$}&
\multicolumn{3}{c}{$\downbracefill$}\\[-3pt]

        1  & 1  & 0 & \cdots   & \cdots    & 0  & 0  & 0          & \cdots  & 0     \\
        0  & 0  & 0 & \cdots   & \cdots    & 1    & -1 & 0          & \cdots  & 0 \\
        0  & 0        & \cdots     & \cdots   & \cdots    & \cdots           & \cdots      & \cdots        & \cdots  & 0 \\
        0  & 0 & \cdots & \cdots         & \cdots    & \cdots          & \cdots              & \cdots        & \cdots  & 0 \\
    \end{array}\right]
\]

%\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ok, that works great thanks. I will run the code locally before posting question in future.